# Trouble declaring a global array of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, global

The following code, in global scope, doesn't compile:

```
const char *one = "1";
const char *two = "2";
char *nums[2] = {one, two};
```

The error message is "initializer element not constant" - which surprises me, since the variables one and two are both declared as constant. Making nums `const` doesn't fix the problem.  Declaring nums with string literals (`char *nums[2] = {"1", "2"};`) *does* fix the problem, but for readability reasons, I'd rather not do it this way in my actual code.

Is there a decent way to get this working?

Comment: `constant` doesn't mean `const`, it means a literal, like `"bla bla"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not allow global initialization from variables, even if those are themselves `const`. By comparison to C++, C has a much stricter notion of a "constant expression".

At present, `one` is a *mutable* pointer, so it cannot possibly be considered a constant expression, but even the more correct `const char * const one = "1";` wouldn't do in C. (It'd be fine in C++.)

You'll have to say:

```
const char * nums[2] = { "1", "2" };
```

Comment: Note that `const` in C doesn't really mean "constant"; it means read-only.  And if you provide an initializer for an array, you don't need to specify the length: `const char *nums[] = { "1", "2" };`

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks, "read-only" a good way to think of `const`!

Comment: If you want both the individual named strings and the array, you can write `char const * const one = nums[0];` etc.

Comment: @jcsalomon: Well, not really, not at the global scope in any case -- it's just the same situation in reverse. You either just use `nums[0]`, or you can make a local pointer inside a function for convenience.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good catch.  I got confused with a technique I’ve actually used, for initializing trees or lists at compile time.  Something like `struct Node root[] = {[0] = {.next = root+1}, [1] = {.next = root+2}, [2] = {0}};`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `#define`ing your constants instead

```
#define ONE "1"
#define TWO "2"
/* const */ char *nums[2] = {ONE, TWO};
```

Comment: The `const` on the third line is still a *very* good idea, since the pointers do point to read-only memory.

Comment: A problem with what you describe is that `ONE == ONE` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *one = "1";
const char *two = "2";
```

Here both one and two are string const irrespective of specifying const qualifier.
I mean `char *one  = "1"`;would be same as const `char *one = "1"` .
In C string `const` are initialized by defining during declaration and they remain unaltered through out the execution of the program.

`char *nums[2];` is an array of char pointers which could be used in two ways.

**first way:**

```
const char *one = "1";
const char *two = "2";
char *num[2] = {"1","2"}; // this is same as creating array of string const
```

**second way:**

```
const char *one = "1";
const char *two = "2";

main()
{
   int len1 = strlen(one)+1;
   int len2 = strlen(two)+1;
   nums[0] = (char *)malloc(len1);
   nums[1] = (char *)malloc(len2);
   strcpy(nums[0],one);
   strcpy(nums[1],two);
}
```